# Asymmetric Transition Probability Matrix with uniform stationary distribution

Tags: markov-chains

I am solving a discrete  Markov chain problem. For this I need a **Markov chain** whose **stationary distribution** is **uniform(or near to uniform distribution)** and **transition probability matrix** is ***asymmetric***.

[ Markov chains like Metropolis hasting has uniform stationary distribution but transition probability matrix is symmetric ]

Answer (score 0):

Take the matrix $A$ such that for every $i$, we have:

1. $A_{i,i} =0.5$
2. $A_{i,i+1}=0.5$ (for $i=n$, set $A_{n,0}=0.5$)

Then it is not symmetric, but has a uniform stationary distribution.